# Problems while adding facebook tab to my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook page missing in drop-down of page list when adding page tab to my facebook page using add to page link.

Page I want a app to be added is disabled in the drop down list.

Comment: are you admin of the page?

Comment: yes of course..this basic stuff everybody know!

Comment: i would not be so sure about that. are you 100% sure you are admin, and not just moderator or something else?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure, In fact I can see all my other pages in the list, but problem is only for one specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update to people who are wondering about the same issue, here's a solution:

If your page has **Page owner** (Who has claimed business manager of Facebook page), then no one can add tabs to page not even Admin or Manager of page. 
*Only one person can be a page owner unlike manager role and he can add tabs to a page*.

If your page do not have any page owner, then Facebook Page managers or admins can add tabs to Facebook page.